# How to put eng.cube.lm in xcode 5.0.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

when i add tessdata folder in bundle then generates this error :

/Users/cepl/Desktop/NumberOCR/NumberOCR/tessdata/eng.cube.lm:8: premature EOF
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lex failed with exit code 1

Comment: Be aware that if you want to submit this app for the AppStore you will need to have Xcode 5.1.1 or newer : [Build Your Apps With Xcode 5.1.1](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04252014a)

Comment: show the full crash report

Comment: Lex NumberOCR/tessdata/eng.cube.lm
    cd /Users/cepl/Desktop/NumberOCR
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    lex -o/Users/cepl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NumberOCR-cvydwrgrfkmkrvbuthswkprwbeam/Build/Intermediates/NumberOCR.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NumberOCR.build/DerivedSources/eng.cube.yy.m /Users/cepl/Desktop/NumberOCR/NumberOCR/tessdata/eng.cube.lm

Comment: Hi i am facing the same problem, can anyone plz help me

Answer (score 21):

Make sure you select the "Create folder references" option, when adding the tessdata folder to your project.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/wiki/Installation):

> NOTE: This library currently requires the tessdata folder to be linked
>   as a referenced folder instead of a symbolic group. If Tesseract can't
>   find a language file in your own project, it's probably because you
>   created the tessdata folder as a symbolic group instead of a
>   referenced folder. It should look like this if you did it correctly:
>
> [image]
>
> Note how the tessdata folder has a blue icon, indicating it was
>   imported as a referenced folder instead of a symbolic group.

Trashing the current folder and adding it again as a folder reference should solve the problem.

Comment: answer is correct for Xcode 10.0 Process> 1  Right click on project main folder choose "show in Finder" , copy tessdata folder and paste into finder location 2. drag to under project main folder into Xcode project navigation section , choose "Create folder reference" option. 3. make sure icon will be blue clolor . error gone

Comment: Thanks Also works in Xcode 10.2.1 :) :)
Saved my time